# Update column2 if column1 is a number

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to update an int column with the values of a nvarchar() column in sql server 2008. How can I update the column if the value is numeric but leave it null if it isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ISNUMERIC()` to check if the column containing varchar data for the update consists entirely of numbers:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET col = CAST(varcharcol AS INT)
WHERE ISNUMERIC(varcharcol) = 1
```